# Summation Problem (lower limit is variable)

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

$$\sum_{j=i}^n 2$$

---

I am having difficulty solving this summation. Can i have hint or solution to this problem?

Comment: Would it look more familiar to you if you factored out the 2?

Comment: You are adding 2 'n' times

Comment: @Shailesh : No, that's not what's happening: The lower bound is $i$, not $1$. $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy. Yes. You are right.

Answer (score 5):

So the first index is $i$, the last is $n$, basically you are adding the number $2$ a certain number of times, that is the number of terms in your summation. This number of terms is $n-i+1$ ("last index" minus "first  index" plus "one"), unless $n<i$, where the convention is typically to consider you are summing nothing (you would have a negative number of terms to add).

So the answer is $2(n-i+1)$ or $0$, which can be noted 
$$\max \{2(n-i+1),0\}\,.$$

An additional note: the title says "lower limit is variable". Since you did not ask about $n$ as  "upper limit is variable", I am adding a few comments. What can be misleading is that $i$ is often used as a dummy index, esp. in series.

Here,  the summation dummy variable is $j$, going from $i$ to $n$. In this case, I would say that neither  $i$ nor $n$ is "variable" (adjective): they do not vary in the context of the summation, they are unspecified constants. But in a bigger problem, for instance in a program, each could be considered a "a variable" (noun).

Answer (score 3):

You have

$$\sum_{j=i}^n2=2\sum_{j=i}^n1\;,$$

which is simply the number of integers $j$ that satisfy the inequality $i\le j\le n$. That number is $n-i+1$ if $i\le n$ and $0$ otherwise, so

$$\sum_{j=i}^n2=\begin{cases}
n-i+1,&\text{if }i\le n\\
0,&\text{if }i>n\;.
\end{cases}$$

If you’re not sure why there are $n-i+1$ integers in that range, note that the range includes $i+0,i+1,i+2,\ldots,i+(n-i)$, so it contains exactly as many integers as the set

$$\{0,1,\ldots,n-i\}\;.$$

There are $n-i$ positive integers in that set, and the $0$ is the $(n-i+1)$-st member.

Answer (score 2):

$$\sum^n_{j=i} 2 = 2 \sum^n_{j=i}1 \underbrace{=}_{n-i+1 \text{ numbers to sum}} 2(n - i + 1)$$

Answer (score 1):

ok, Let's look at the case $i=50$ and $n=90$:
$$
\sum_{j=i}^n 2 = \sum_{j=50}^{90} 2 = \overbrace{2 + 2 + 2 + \cdots + 2}^\text{How many 2s ?}.
$$

The question is just how many $2$s are added.  Going from $50$ to $90$, the difference is $500 - 90=40$, so there are $41$ terms, each a $2$.  So
$$
\overbrace{2 + 2 + 2 + \cdots + 2}^\text{41 terms} = 41\times 2.
$$
$$
41 = 90 - 50 + 1 = n - i + 1.
$$
So you have $(n-i+1)\times 2$.

Perhaps what is at issue is this: In the list $1,2,3,\ldots,73$ there are $73$ numbers, but how do you tell how many there are in a list like $50,51,52,53,\ldots,90$?  When you subtract you get $90-50 = 40$.  The "fencepost error", as some call it, is to think that therefore there are $40$ numbers.  But if that is applied to $1,2,3,\ldots,73$, one would conclude that there are $73-1=72$ numbers.  That one has to add $1$ after subtracting may be what caused the difficulty (but maybe the original poster can say more about that.)

Comment: You meant to say "Going from $50$ to $90$, the difference is $\color{red}{90} - \color{red}{50} = 40$, so there are $41$ terms, each a $2$."